# Связывание состояния Progress Bar в MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm

Я написал программу для копирования файлов и хочу, чтобы состояние процесса копирования отображалось в progress bar. Мне нужно сделать это с помощью mvvm. Как привязать progress bar к view model?

Answer (score 3):

Пример привязки при условии, что Progress Bar задан в разметке:

```
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding Percentage, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

-

```
public class ViewModelX : ViewModel
{
    private readonly BackgroundWorker worker;
    private readonly ICommand runWorkCommand;
    private int Percentage;

    public ViewModelX()
    {
        this.runWorkCommand = new DelegateCommand(o => this.worker.RunWorkerAsync, o => !this.worker.IsBusy);

        this.worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        this.worker.DoWork += this.DoWork;
        this.worker.ProgressChanged += this.ProgressChanged;
    }

    // Использовать для запуска через UI
    public ICommand RunWorkCommand
    {
        get { return this.runWorkCommand; }
    }

    public int Percentage
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Percentage;
        }
        private set
        {
            if (this.Percentage != value)
            {
                this.Percentage = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(() => this.Percentage);
            }
        }
    }

    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Выполнить длительную задачу здесь
    }

    private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Percentage = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не ясно, что подразумевается под длительной задачей? Поместить метод копирования файлов в метод DoWork?
У меня конструктор DelegateCommand принимает параметр  Action action и все